# Is there any all_coeffs() for multivariable polynomials in sympy?

Tags: sympy, polynomials

I  want to extract all coefficients (INCLUDING ZEROS) of a multariable polynomial using sympy.

Sympy offers all_coeffs() but it only works for univariate. Otherwise I get this error `PolynomialError: multivariate polynomials not supported`

For example for a polynomial x^3+y^3+x*y+1 I woud like the output to be `[3,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]`

Comment: Can you be clear about precisely what you want as output with an example? What would the expected output be for say `x**10 + y**10 + x*y`?

Comment: Sorry I will edit my response, good point

Comment: I presume that the 3s should really be 1s. If you want a flat list of coefficients then this implies that there is some monomial ordering but you haven't said which you want and your suggested output doesn't correspond to any of the standard ones (lex, grevlex, etc). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the monomials of interest then you can see what their coefficients are in your expression. You have to watch out for requesting a monomial coefficient of `x*y` in an expression with terms like `x*y*z`, however. The following routine handles that by zeroing out any variables in the coefficient that is obtained. It also has a routine to create monomials of interest.

```py
def all_coeffs(expr,*free):
    x = IndexedBase('x')
    expr = expr.expand()
    free = list(free) or list(expr.free_symbols)
    pows = [p.as_base_exp() for p in expr.atoms(Pow,Symbol)]
    P = {}
    for p,e in pows:
        if p not in free:
            continue
        elif p not in P:
            P[p]=e
        elif e>P[p]:
            P[p] = e
    reps = dict([(f, x[i]) for i,f in enumerate(free)])
    xzero = dict([(v,0) for k,v in reps.items()])
    e = expr.xreplace(reps); reps = {v:k for k,v in reps.items()}
    return dict([(m.xreplace(reps), e.coeff(m).xreplace(xzero) if m!=1 else e.xreplace(xzero)) for m in monoms(*[P[f] for f in free])])

def monoms(*o):
    x = IndexedBase('x')
    f = []
    for i,o in enumerate(o):
        f.append(Poly([1]*(o+1),x[i]).as_expr())
    return Mul(*f).expand().args

>>> eq = x**2 + x*y - 3
>>> all_coeffs(eq)
{1: -3, x**2: 1, x**2*y: 0, x*y: 1, y: 0, x: 0}
>>> all_coeffs(eq, x)
{1: -3, x**2: 1, x: y}
```

Comment: I am more than thankful! Thank you